# How to catch exceptions and redirect to error page in Lift?

Tags: scala, exception, lift

How to make error handlers in Lift? I have html page with some snippets, if one of those snippets throws an exception I want to catch it and redirect to some user friendly error page.

How to do this in catch-all manner? I do not want to put error handling to each snippet separately. I am looking something like [this](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/settings/IApplicationSettings.html#setInternalErrorPage(java.lang.Class)) in Wicket.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When in doubt, check [LiftRules API](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.3/net/liftweb/http/LiftRules.html#exceptionHandler:RulesSeq[ExceptionHandlerPF]).

According [this post](http://old.nabble.com/How-to-log-exceptions--td23429313.html) something like this should work:

```
LiftRules.exceptionHandler.prepend { 
  case ("production", Req(path, "", GetRequest), someException) => { 
    Log.error("MELT DOWN!!") 
    RedirectResponse("/") 
  } 
}
```

The signature of the exception handler type is:

```
type ExceptionHandlerPF = PartialFunction[(Props.RunModes.Value, Req, 
  Throwable), LiftResponse]
```

Comment: What if I don't want to distinguish RunModes etc and only whant to catch all the exceptions which happen not to be handled inside the application?